# DeadlineExceededError for Google Cloud SQL after 60 secs

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We have an script that calls a procedure that sometimes takes more than 60 seconds to execute. When the procedure goes above 60 secs, we get a `DeadlineExceededError`. The error message looks like this:

`DeadlineExceededError: The API call rdbms.Exec() took too long to respond and was cancelled.`

This script is scheduled as a cron and using B8 class back end. Does using a back end have any effect on the timeout limit of a query? What can I do in case of a query taking more than 60 secs to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a cron or backend would give you a longer deadline.  See this FAQ entry:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#sizeqps

Comment: Author already use backend, but the problem is that 60 seconds limit still persist, though it should be 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously a bug, because I run query on backend instance and it also raises DeadlineExceededError after 60 seconds.

Here's the ticket in googleappengine https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9479 and on googlecloudsql https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=71

No response yet.